# Validate image file with carrier wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, carrierwave

how do you validate the file type of the image you're uploading using carrierwave? Currently we're using the code:

```
def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
end
```

But it just validates the extension. If the user changed the extension of a .gif to .jpeg, this will bypass the validation. Any work around for this?

**EDIT**

My research shows that I need to check the mime type of the file for this. How do you do this in carrierwave? The documentation for mimetype in the gem is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I solved this is to use bash command through ruby [from this site](http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2009/06/14/really-finding-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-osx-and-linux/)

Although not the most flexible solution, I find that it works on my situation plus it's the most dependable one.